# MVC3 Move Validation Blocks

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to place all JavaScript at the bottom of a page.  If I move jquery to the bottom it breaks validation on the page.  Is there a way to move validation to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

No, jQuery must be at the top of the page, but most everything else can come after it.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to put all of your styles at the top of the page and all of your scripts at the bottom of the page. You will need to put the references to your JavaScript files above your page specific JavaScript.

Its easy to do in MVC3 if you use helper methods.

The process goes like this:

1. Create helper methods for storing the scripts in the ViewContext
2. Add scripts and references to JavaScript files in the ViewContext in any of your views and partial views
3. Render the scripts at the bottom of the page in the order you need them

If this seems like a lot, take a look at this post:

[MVC executing view code before layout code and ruining my script order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012658/mvc-executing-view-code-before-layout-code-and-ruining-my-script-order/8280410#8280410)

The helper methods simplify what would otherwise be very messy code. Good luck!